# Menu item is not getting visible

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I am inflating a menu item dynamically after specific event occurs. But menu item is not getting visible.

Below is code:

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent){
        appCompatActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        setUpdateText();
        appCompatActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}, new IntentFilter(UPDATE_ACTION));

void setUpdateText() {
    if (mainMenu != null) {
        mainMenu.findItem(R.id.notificationdevicemenu).setVisible(true);
        mainMenu.findItem(R.id.notificationdevicemenu).setEnabled(true);

    }
}
```

And I'm inflating menu like below:

```
  @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
      super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
      mainMenu=menu;
      menu.clear();
      try {
          inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_list_fragment, mainMenu);         
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

Can anyone please tell me why menu is not getting visible. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidating options menu will fire [`onPrepareOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)), not [`onCreateOptionsMenu()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)), which is called once (the first time options menu is displayed). Override `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` and perform necessary changes from there.